# django send email - install time delay between sent emails

Tags: python, django, email

I am learning django and I have a test page that allows a user to "contact us" - and it is working - the emails are being delivered on my local development server.

I have tried for two days now (I have read SO posts, django docs, google and a few tutorials), and cannot workout how to do the following:

**How do I place a time delay so the user would have to wait 3 minutes (or so) before sending the 'contact us' another e-mail?** This would be a feature that prevents the same user bombarding the 'contact_us' with e-mails - the user would have to wait 3 minutes (or so) between e-mails.

I thought of completing this using JQuery, but wouldn't a user be able to bypass a setup of this on the client side?

Here is my models.py file:

```
class Contact(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
email = models.EmailField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=250)
reason = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=REASON_TYPES, default=SELECT_REASON_TYPE, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
message = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=2000)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

def __unicode__(self, ):
    return "Message from: " + str(self.email)
```

Here is my forms.py file:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Contact

        fields = (
            'name',
            'email',
            'reason',
            'message',
        )
        labels = {
            'name': _('Name'),
            'email': _('E-mail'),
            'reason': _('Reason'),
            'message': _('Message'),
        }
        help_texts = {
            'message': _('2,000 character limit'),
        }
        error_messages = {
            'reason': {'validate_min': _('This field is required.')},  # validate_min used on achievement_type in lieu of required field.
        }
```

Here is my views.py file:

```
def contact_us(request):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        save_form = form.save(commit=False)
        send = send_mail(str(save_form.reason), str(save_form.message), str(save_form.email), ['XXX@gmail.com'], fail_silently=True)
        save_form.save()
        messages.success(request, _('message successfully delivered.'))
return render_to_response('contact_us/contact_us.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is my urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    ....
    url(r'^contact_us/', 'contact.views.contact_us', name='contact_us'),
    ....
)
```

Comment: By user, do you mean a registered user of your site that has a login, or just anyone that visits your site?

Comment: Burhan Khalid, I mean both registered users and anyone who visits the site - the unregistered users.

Answer (score 3):

You can use django session variable to store the exact time when the user sent a last email. If the current time is less than 3 minutes, just update your session variable to current time and send the email, otherwise, dont allow user to send the email.

```
def contact_us(request):
    last_send_time = request.session.get('last_email_time',None)
    if last_send_time:
         current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
         diff = current_time - last_send_time
         minutes_diff = divmod(diff.days * 86400 + diff.seconds, 60)
         if minudes_diff[0] > 3: #minutes_diff[0] has difference between current_time and last_send_time
            //Handle this case, user cant send email again
            return render_to_response('contact_us/contact_us.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 
         else:
             request.session['last_email_time'] = current_time



     form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
     if form.is_valid():
         save_form = form.save(commit=False)
         send = send_mail(str(save_form.reason), str(save_form.message), str(save_form.email), ['XXX@gmail.com'], fail_silently=True)
         save_form.save()
         messages.success(request, _('message successfully delivered.'))
         return render_to_response('contact_us/contact_us.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: levi, I am getting the following error that I don't know how to solve: `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'` the line of code is `last_send_time = request.get('last_email_time',None)` . How do I solve this issue?

Comment: @user3354539 oh sorry my bad, it should be request.session  instead of request. I fixed, check it.

Comment: I recently read that sessions expire, for example, when the browser is closed. This means that if I request an email, and close the browser, can I then request again?